# How can i install findbugs in netbeans 11.3

Tags: findbugs, netbeans-11

-I can not find findbugs in availiable plugins to install

if i try source-->inspect and choose to install findbugs from there netbeans says that findbugs can not be downloaded

is there a way to activate it?

[image]

Comment: refer this [docs](https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/wiki/NetBeans-Tutorial) to install or enable findbugs.

Comment: This does not work since i can not find findbugs in availiable plugins

Comment: Try as per this [docs](https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/java/code-inspect.html) by adding a jar file.

Comment: This does not work also because i can not install findbugs needed as i showed in the above images

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few basic points first:

- The FindsBugs plugin was included in NetBeans 11.2, but it's not in 11.3, and I get the same result as you ("*...module has not been downloaded*") when trying to install it on NetBeans 11.3. See [this comment from a member of the NetBeans team](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/netbeans-users/202001.mbox/%3Cpony-5f70a9b0f6f1d458a94cad15575807621188316e-84097ac6f6f9a106f0584ff1775f3b0e96a8ac6d@users.netbeans.apache.org%3E): "*The find bugs module hasn't been donated yet it's due in a later donation*".
- I raised NetBeans Report Bug Report 576 a couple of years ago on FindBugs that has not been addressed: [The FindBugs plugin works with JDK8 but not with JDK10](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-576). So even if you could install it, I think it would be useless with code using any version of Java more recent than JDK 8. Even the FindBugs web site only claims to "analyze programs compiled for [any version of Java, from 1.0 to 1.8](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)".
- Regardless of all that, FindsBugs is no longer alive. From 11/2/16: "*[I'm really sorry to say, but FindBugs project in its current form is dead](https://mailman.cs.umd.edu/pipermail/findbugs-discuss/2016-November/004321.html)*". So don't use FindBugs any more. It's not maintained or supported.
- Instead, use SpotBugs, which is "[the spiritual successor of FindBugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/)".

Having said that, as far as I know there is no NetBeans plugin for SpotBugs either, although [one brave developer documented how to do it yourself](http://www.enricoscantamburlo.it/2017/04/03/adding-spotbugs-support-to-a-netbeans-platform-application/) if you feel so inclined.

However, you can use SpotBugs if you have a Maven or Gradle project:

- The Maven plugin is constrained [to use JDK 8 to run this plugin. This is a requirement imposed by Spotbugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/spotbugs-maven-plugin/). I haven't tried that.
- You can get [Gradle plugins for SpotBugs from here](https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=spotbugs). I haven't tried any of those either.