# issue while installing FindBugs in NetBeans 8-2

Tags: java, testing, netbeans, findbugs

I am trying to install findBugs on NetBeans 8.2 and I am getting the following error:
[image]

Can you please help!

Thank you!

Comment: Why install it. I believe it already comes with NetBeans 8.2 (right up to NeatBeans 11.2 I think) and is part of its **Inspector** features. To find out if your NetBeans IDE has FindBugs, load a class into the IDE, from the NetBeans menu bar select **Source → Inspector →** In the displayed dialog choose: **FindBugs** from the **Confiuration** drop-down combo box. Select the **Inspect** button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does anyone know how to fix this error to install Findbugs into Netbeans 8.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61758539/does-anyone-know-how-to-fix-this-error-to-install-findbugs-into-netbeans-8-2)